# Android. Scaling layout with 2 webviews in it

Tags: android, webview, scale

I need to scale layout with 2 webviews in it on pinch to zoom.
[image: img]

I've tried to set scaleX and scaleY for layout on gesture. It works but content in webview displayed in old resolution so it looks bad on big zoom.
Can someone give me an idea how should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of what you want to achieve, but i guess you want to enable both webView to zoom separately?

For each webview instance, enable the `ZoomControls` function inside `onCreate`

```
// Allow Pinch to Zoom
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
// Disable the zoom overlay control
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: no, they should zoom together. and size of each should also be zoomed